# In a Tauri app how to copy a file in src to BaseDirectory.AppConfig

Tags: tauri

I have an image file in src/foo.gif and I want to copy it to the `BaseDirectory.AppConfig` directory via React/js.

In App.js

```
function imageToUint8Array(image, context) {
  context.width = image.width;
  context.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  // `getImageData().data` is a `Uint8ClampedArray`, which differs from `Uint8Array` only in
  // how data is treated when values are being *set*, so it is valid to perform the conversion
  // into a `Uint8Array`.
  return new Uint8Array(context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data.buffer);
}

const image = new Image();
// stackoverflow logo
image.src = `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...`;

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

await writeBinaryFile('test7.png', new Uint8Array(imageToUint8Array(image, context)), { dir: BaseDirectory.AppConfig });
```

In tauri.conf.json:

```
      "fs": {
            "all": true,
            "scope": ["$APPDATA/*", "$APPCONFIG/*","$LOCALDATA/*", "$APP/*", "$DESKTOP/*", "$RESOURCE/*"]
        },
```

But the file is not readable. Also I'm not sure if I need to first convert the image file to UInt8Array format. I wonder if I could simply copy the file.